# Subgroup of O(Q)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V,Q)$ be a quadratic space over some field $K$, where $V$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension eight. I would like to understand the structure of the subgroup of the group $O(Q)$ of orthogonal transformations which fix a given three-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$. Can anyone give a concrete description of this subgroup (there might be different possibilities depending on $Q$ and/or $W$)? I find it hard to do this kind of concrete calculations, any hints would be welcome...

(I am already very happy with a description of what happens when $W$ is *totally* isotropic for $Q$.)

Comment: Do you know anything about the quadratic form $Q$?  Could it be the zero form?  What is its isotropy index?  Do you know anything about the restriction of $Q$ to $W$?

Comment: You can suppose that it is not degenerate to start with... Also you can suppose that $Q$ is zero when restricted to $W$. This is a strong hypothesis, but knowing something about this case would already be very useful to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, here's a solution that ought to work for any algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ in the case where $Q$ is nondegenerate.  This is all based on a bunch of matrix calculations, so I don't have proofs for some of it, but it ought to be correct unless I've made a calculation mistake.  The obvious way to check it would be to prove these statements rigorously.

Let $W$ be an arbitrary subspace of $V$, and let $G \leq O(V)$ be the group of orthogonal transformations that leave $W$ invariant.  Define
$$
R \;=\; W \cap W^\perp \qquad\text{and}\qquad S \;=\; W + W^\perp.
$$
Note that $W^\perp$ is invariant under the action of $G$, and therefore $R$ and $S$ are also invariant.

The structure of $G$ is as follows.  First, there is a short exact sequence
$$
1 \;\;\to\;\; A \;\;\to\;\; G \;\;\to\;\; O(S) \;\;\to\;\; 1
$$
where $A$ is an abelian group isomorphic to $K^d$ for some value of $d$.  The homomorphism $G \to O(S)$ is surjective because of [Witt's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt%27s_theorem).

The group $O(S)$ is a semidirect product.  Specifically,
$$
O(S) \;\cong\; \bigl( \text{Lin}(R,W/R) \times \text{Lin}(R,W^\perp/R) \bigr) \;\rtimes\; \bigl(O(R) \times O(W/R) \times O(W^\perp/R) \bigr).
$$
Here $\text{Lin}(R,W/R)$ is the additive abelian group of all linear functions $R\to W/R$, and $\text{Lin}(R,W^\perp/R)$ is similarly an additive abelian group.  Since $Q$ restricts to the null quadratic form on $R$, the orthogonal group $O(R)$ is the same as $GL(R)$.  Moreover, since $Q$ is null on $R$, the quotients $W/R$ and $W^\perp/R$ are quadratic spaces, and $O(W/R)$ and $O(W^\perp/R)$ are the corresponding orthogonal groups.  Note also that the quadratic forms on $W/R$ and $W^\perp/R$ are nondegenerate.

As for the question of connectivity: since the kernels $A$ and $\text{Lin}(R,W/R)\times\text{Lin}(R,W^\perp/R)$ are both connected, the group $G$ will be connected if and only if the groups $O(R)$, $O(W/R)$, and $O(W^\perp/R)$ are connected.  Note that $O(R) \cong GL(R)$, while $O(W/R)$ and $O(W^\perp/R)$ are orthogonal groups for nondegenerate quadratic spaces.  (Perhaps it is obvious to you whether these are connected -- I do not know much about the connectedness of orthogonal groups over arbitrary fields.)

**Edit:**  Here is a bit more information on the kernel $A$ of the epimorphism $G \to O(S)$.  Since $Q|_{R\times S} = 0$, the quadratic form $Q$ defines a bilinear map $B \colon R \times (V/S) \to K$,
and it is not hard to show that $B$ is a perfect pairing.  It follows that the action of an element $g\in G$ on  $V/S$ is entirely determined by the action of $g$ on $R$.  In particular, every element of $A$ acts trivially on $V/S$.  Therefore, every element $g\in A$ has the form
$$
g(v) \;=\; v + \varphi(\pi(v))
$$
where $\pi\colon V \to V/S$ is the quotient map, and $\varphi\colon V/S \to S$ is a linear map.  Thus $A$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of the abelian group $\text{Lin}(V/S,S)$.

To be specific, $A$ is isomorphic to the group of all linear maps $\varphi\colon V/S \to S$ that
satisfy the following conditions:

1. The range of $\varphi$ lies in $R$.
2. The map $\varphi$ is "antisymmetric" with respect to $B$ in the sense that
   $$
   B(\varphi(u),v) + B(\varphi(v),u) = 0
   $$
   for all $u,v \in V/S$.

In particular, $A$ is isomorphic to the additive group of all $m\times m$ antisymmetric matrices over $K$, where $m = \dim(R)$.

Comment: May I ask why the kernel of $G \to O(S)$ is an additive group?

Comment: @Belg:  I have added some information about this kernel to the end of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the most basic case is when $W^\perp = V$.  In this case, $Q$ induces a quadratic form $Q/W$ on $V/W$, and the group has the following structure:
$$
\text{Lin}(W,V/W) \rtimes \bigl(GL(W) \times O(Q/W)\bigr).
$$
Here $\text{Lin}(W,V/W)$ is the additive group of all linear functions $W\to V/W$, and $GL(W)\times O(Q/W)$ acts on $\text{Lin}(W,V/W)$ in the obvious way.

Is this the kind of information you're looking for?  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "concrete description".  Would you prefer something in terms of matrices?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't necessarily need a description in terms of matrices; abstract algebraic groups are fine. However the condition $W^\perp = V$ implies of course that $Q$ is degenerate, which is something I'd like to avoid. Could you say something on the non-degenerate case? I'd like to understand (at least) whether the group is connected or not...

Comment: I'm sorry, what does it mean for the group to be connected in this context?  Is $K$ the complex numbers?  My impression was that you were mostly interested in the case where $K$ is a finite field.

Comment: You can assume that K is algebraically closed of characteristic zero - and by connected I mean Zariski-connected...

Comment: OK, I have added another answer which should be more helpful.